# This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 21.0.0 or above

Tags: android, windows

(envirnment: Windows 7
             Eclipse
)

When I update in Android SDK Manager, I have selected all SDKs, platforms, samples and so on. After restart Eclipse, when I try to access Android SDK Manager, I got this message:
**Location of the android sdk has not been setup in the preferences**
!

When I tried to locate SDK in Window->preference->Android,
 I got This warning:
**This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 21.0.0 or above.  Current version is 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.  Please update ADT to the latest version.**
!

I have tried to update latest ADT. It shows me: **Cannot complete the request. See the error log for details. Android Development Tools will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.**

Comment: Right? And your question is what exactly? Have you perhaps considered the slightest possibility of giving some thought to perhaps _upgrading your ADT!_ :-)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html I have tried to install Eclipse the latest ADT. It shows me: Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
Android Development Tools will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?..

Answer (score 16):

Go to Help > Install New Software...
In "Work With" select "Android Developer Tools Updater Site" 
(If not available, click Add... and enter: Name: Android Developer Tools Updater Site, 
Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)

Check "Developer Tools" and "NDK Plugins"

Answer (score 1):

> Location of the android sdk has not been setup in the preferences !

Go to Window > Preferences > Android and indicate where you installed the SDK.

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 21.0.0 or above. Current version is 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395. Please update ADT to the latest version.

Go to Help > Check for Updates and update the Android-related plugins.

Comment: Thanks! But I got following warning this time:Insufficient access privileges to apply this update.

Android Dalvik Debug Monitor Service

Comment: @RobbieYJ: Perhaps you need to run as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I have manually downloaded the ADT-22.3.0.zip and installed in eclipse. This worked for me hope this will help someone.

See the instructions below

If you are still unable to use Eclipse to download the ADT plugin as a remote update site, you can download the ADT zip file to your local machine and manually install it:

1. Download the ADT Plugin zip file (do not unpack it):
   ADT-22.3.0.zip  http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.3.0.zip
2. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
3. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
4. In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
5. Select the downloaded ADT-22.3.0.zip file and click OK.
6. Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
7. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
8. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
   Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
9. If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
10. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

To update your plugin once you've installed using the zip file, you will have to follow these steps again instead of the default update instructions.

The same instructions can be found in this link http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

Why I put this answer?

> Go to your eclipse, click on Help -> install new software -> Add... ->
>
> type in 'ADT plugin' for name,
>
> type in https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ for URL,
>
> then a couple selections including ADT will show up in the window, click on the things you want to update then click okay, and you will be able to update your ADT.

I advise you to immediately click the "Add" button and fill fields like in the above quotation, because I have tried several times to install by selecting the "Work with .." etc. and the installation had an errors, and it was just a couple of times, and when I chose the "Add" button at the first time the entire installation was successful.

Maybe someone also had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps upgrading the Eclipse solving this problem .
I had the same problem , trying upgrading ADT online and offline(downloading the package from the [site](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) , but nothing change until I downloading the newer eclipse.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the above solution but unable to update the eclipse.
To update the eclipse firstly we have to uninstall the developer tools from the eclipse and reinstall it in the eclipse to resolve this issue.